# using re.sub with groups

Tags: python, regex

```
re.sub("([^\\[\s\\]]+)([\\]\s]*)( [>|=|<] )",replace(r'\1')+r'\2'+r'\3',s)
```

This doesn't pass the first group to replace function and rather passes `r'\1'` as a string.

Please suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: in `[\\]\s]*` part you didn't open the bracket

Comment: not sure but it should be `([\]\s]*)` in order to be escaped

Comment: i am sure its correct. Hint its not a raw string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a string to the method replace.

The group will only be evaluated in the `sub` method. You could do a separate `search` to get your result, untested though since you have not posted the value from `s` nor the `replace` function:

```
pattern = "([^\\[\s\\]]+)([\\]\s]*)( [>|=|<] )"
re.sub(pattern, replace(re.search(pattern, s).group(1))+r'\2'+r'\3',s)
```

Here is another method possible better suited for you:

```
# this method is called for every match
def replace(match):
    group1 = match.group(1)
    group2 = match.group(2)
    group3 = match.group(3)
    # process groups
    return "<your replacement>"

s = "<your string>"
pattern = "([^\\[\s\\]]+)([\\]\s]*)( [>|=|<] )"
newtext= re.sub(pattern, replace, s)

print(newtext)
```

Comment: Thanks!.How can I extend this to work for replacing multiple instances of the match?

Comment: @anuj I edited my answer to include a possibility that is probably better suited for your needs.